# Compounding Finance Portfolio using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I am trying to create a finance back tester for finance portfolio construction. I have imported the historical data and created variables for equity and bond allocation in terms of % & fiat terms(equity_value). I have managed to enter the value in the starting year (1975 as an example) however I would like to use calculate the compounded returns (e.g 1975 Return was 37.20% so in 1976 it should have the money invested e.g $100,000 * 1.372 (Last years return)).

I have tried to use the cumprod() method however it keeps coming up with errors I can say I have put quite a few hours into this and I can see where I'm going wrong tried lots of other stackoverflow posts and other blog posts still not sure where I'm going wrong using the cumprod() method.

Thanks for your help.

Code Which Works

`

```
Portfolio_Value = input("Please enter your Portfolio Value in $ ")
Portfolio_Value = float(Portfolio_Value)
print("\n"+ "You'r portfolio value is $" + str(Portfolio_Value))

Equity_Allocation = input("Please enter your equity allocation in %")
Bond_Allocation = 100 - float(Equity_Allocation)
print("{:.2}".format(Equity_Allocation))
print("{:.2}".format(Bond_Allocation))

Equity_Value = float(Portfolio_Value) * float(Equity_Allocation)
Bond_Value = float(Portfolio_Value) * float(Bond_Allocation)

import datetime

start_date = datetime.datetime(1975,1,1)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2021,1,1)

df2 = df[::-1]

rowindex = df2.index[49]

df2.loc[rowindex, "Total Money Invested"] = Equity_Value
print(df2)
```

`

Broken Code

```
df2["Total Equity Value"] = df2.cumprod(axis = 1) *df2[" Return"]
```

print(df2)

Comment: Would you be able to give a sample of your dataframes, e.g. `df.head()` and `df2.head()`?  It would be easier to see what types of data are in each column.  Also, what was the error message you received when running your broken code?

Comment: If your " Return" column is filled with decimals (e.g. `0.372` for the 1975), then you should instead do something like this: `df2["Total Equity Value"] = (df2[" Return"] + 1).cumprod() * Equity_Value` - which will calculate the cumulative product of your returns, and then multiply this by the equity value.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the compounding is `initial_val * (1 + r).cumprod()`.

Here is an example using daily stock prices (excluding adjustments such as stock splits and dividends), using AAPL history from Yahoo finance:

```py
import yfinance as yf

df = yf.Ticker('AAPL').history(period='2y', interval='1d')
df['returns'] = (df['Close'] / df['Close'].shift() - 1).fillna(0)
```

Now, say, you invested $100K two years ago in AAPL:

```py
initial_val = 100_000
shares = initial_val / df['Close'][0]
today_val = shares * df['Close'][-1]
>>> today_val
253467.53938414634
```

Using returns compounding, you get the same:

```py
df['val'] = (initial_val * (1 + df['returns']).cumprod())

>>> df['val'].tail(1)
Date
2022-04-13    253467.539384
Name: val, dtype: float64

>>> df['val'].plot()
```

[image]

Comment: When using my data which I have checked I have used your cumprod() method but using my data frame instead of yfinance API as the API doesn't provide old enough data for my use. However it is still not working the multiplication is wrong and it is not compounding the other lines in the dataframe. I have used the following code df2["Equity Portfolio Value"] = df2["Total Money Invested"] * (1 + df2["Return"]).cumprod()

print(df2)